# MonoTouch License Invalid

Tags: ios, licensing, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, novell

I have an issue with MonoTouch thinking my machine is a new computer every time I update OS X, and I have to reactivate my license. Unfortunately, I am now trying to reactivate but it detects I've already reached my two device limit.

Normally, I would contact support to resolve it, but the support staff does not exist. I've contacted Novell but they tell me they have no way of supporting the product or effecting the license loaded in their database anymore, and that I may simply have to wait until they decide to issue refunds for the licenses sometime down the line.

In the mean time, is there anything I can do to edit my existing license to be accepted, or is their any way to hack MonoTouch itself to work with this license or else bypass the license check? I'm dead in the water with testing any changes until I get this working or Xamarin releases it's IDE.

Thanks,

~Chris

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the transition is finished, did you try to reactivate?

http://xamarin.com/support.html

Answer (score 0):

If MT support is unable/unwilling to help, then you're screwed.  I can't recall anyone being able to workaround an activation problem since this whole drama started.